# Detecting similar web pages

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing

I have a system which crawls the net and takes a screenshot of web pages. At the moment i simply just hash the image file ( stored as a png ). However this doesn't work well with pages that either have a count of comments on a article in a blog. Or a view count.

So my question is what would be the best way to detect these changes? Which algorithm would work best?

Comment: Its unclear what you actually want to do ... in most cases comparing the textual markup of the pages would be far simpler than image processing.

Comment: The html markup can be very different yet produce the same page. For example. Links on the page could be very different. As i mention i want to detect pages which are similar so i can display it to the user as one landing page rather than multiple pages which look the same.

Comment: "So if you can suggest java libraries that would be perfect." - asking for library recommendations is off topic on SO. I suggest you edit out that line as it will attract close votes.

Comment: @samgak, I added Java in there because people may give me solutions that are not in the language I need them to be in. However I have removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

A naive but very easily implemented method would be to wipe out all numeric characters from every page and compare just the character content of them.

Comment: I am not looking for an easily implemented solution, I was looking for the best way of solving my problem. The easiest implemented method is actually checking pixel by pixel, and checking if a specific % of pixels are the same or not. However this may not be the best solution, which is the reason I wanted to ask this question.

Comment: If you prefer the hard way, Google search for "text similarity measures",
This is an example :
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.332.4480&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0):

So first we want to detect the areas with the change. A simple good way is just to take the difference between the two images and than look for all the areas with difference higher than zero. 
After that we would look at every group of points and look at those points in the original image and try to detect numbers using some OCR software.

General algorithm:

1. Diff = Im1 - Im2
2. Threshold Diff to get the threshold image ThIm, i.e. if Diff(x,y) > 0 = ThIm(x,y) = 1 other wise ThIm(x,y) = 0.
3. Find connected component in ThIm
4. For each connected component find the bounding box around it.
5. Crop the original image using the bounding box
6. Run OCR on the cropped area and check if you found numbers